# Container creation differences with docker and podman

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, podman

### Objective

Transfer the [`RabbitMQ` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) from one computer (which is using `docker`, and has access to internet) to another one (which is using `podman` and has no access to internet).

### What I did

1. `docker pull rabbitmq`
2. `docker save -o rabbitmq.tar rabbitmq`
3. Transfer of the `rabbitmq.tar` file from computer 1 to computer 2
4. `podman import rabbitmq.tar rabbitmq:latest`
5. `podman run -d --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 localhost/rabbitmq:latest`

### Issue

The command at step 5 returns the following error: `Error: no command or entrypoint provided, and no CMD or ENTRYPOINT from image`

### What I tried

I also tried the following as an alternative for step 4:
`podman import --change CMD=/bin/bash --change ENTRYPOINT=/bin/sh rabbitmq.tar rabbitmq:latest`.
This in turn returns the following error: `Error: crun: executable file '/bin/sh' not found in $PATH: No such file or directory: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found`.

How can I use RabbitMQ with podman on this offline computer?

Comment: You should use `podman load` instead of `import`. As import will not fetch everything

Comment: This seems to have a greater effect than `import` though it leads to another error now (`Error: payload does not match any of the supported image formats`). I'll try and fix this now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This error led me to a particular [GitHub issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13139) which solved my problem

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - but bear in mind the guidelines for [how to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).